# Calculate category percentage impact on total percentage

Tags: excel, math, calculation

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the total positive or negative impact one category out of several categories, has had on the total average score. Example data:

| Category | Sample | Failed | Passed | Score | Impact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 100 | 10 | 40 | 80.0% | ? |
| Second | 50 | 18 | 82 | 82.0% | ? |
| Third | 73 | 7 | 66 | 90.4% | ? |
| Total | 223 | 35 | 188 | 84.3% |  |

How would I calculate this? Would this be correct?

Base formula: `(category% - total%) * (category sample / total sample) = IMPACT`

First category impact: `(80.0% - 84.3%) * (100 / 223) = -0.965%`

Second category impact: `(82.0% - 84.3%) * (50 / 223) = -1.034%`

Third category impact: `(90.4% - 84.3%) * (73 / 223) = +1.999%`

Comment: Sorry if it is what you're suggesting, but I would calculate the total score without the particular category and than the impact would be real total score - this virtual total score, right? Do not know how to approach this in plain excel, but here is video about how to it could be done with dax so PowerPivot in excel should manage that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-x8gnMNj-w Just a thought.

Comment: The only way I can get 84.3% as the total score is to divide 188 by 223. The average of the individual percentage scores is 84.13. So I think it's unlikely that you would get a consistent result by weighting the percentage differences.